# java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: Spark dataframe with excel error - Scala

Tags: excel, scala, apache-spark, dataframe, apache-spark-sql

I am new to spark. I have a excel file that I need to read into a Dataframe. I am using the `com.crealytics.spark.excel` library to achieve this. The following is my code:

```
 val df = hiveContext.read.format("com.crealytics.spark.excel")
         .option("useHeader", "true")
         .option("treatEmptyValuesAsNulls", "true")
         .load("file:///data/home/items.xlsx")
```

The above code runs without any error. And I am also able to count the number of rows in the `df` using `df.count`. But when I try to print the `df` using `df.show`, it throws an error saying:

`java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: scala.util.matching.Regex.unapplySeq(Ljava/lang/CharSequence;)Lscala/Option;`

I am using **Spark 1.6, Java 1.8 and scala 2.10.5**.
I am not sure why this is happening. How do I solve this error and look at the data in the `df` ?

**UPDATE:**

I also tried using the `StructType` to define the schema and impose it during the loading the data into `df`:

```
 val newschema = StructType(List(StructField("1", StringType, nullable = true),
      StructField("2", StringType, nullable = true),
      StructField("3", StringType, nullable = true),
      StructField("4", StringType, nullable = true),
      StructField("5", StringType, nullable = true),
      StructField("6", StringType, nullable = true),
      StructField("7", StringType, nullable = true),
      StructField("8", StringType, nullable = true),
      StructField("9", StringType, nullable = true),
      StructField("10", StringType, nullable = true)))
val df = hiveContext.read.schema(newschema).format("com.crealytics.spark.excel")...
```

This doesn't help and I get the same error as before when I try to display the `df`.

**UPDATE-2:**

I also tried loading the `df` using `SQLContext`. It still gives me the same error.

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: consider adding some information about your environment, like, for example, java version, scala version, and version of the used spark.

Comment: Added the versions. @AndreyTyukin

Comment: Whether your excel has data or empty?

Comment: Of course, it has data. I am able to count the number of rows using `df.count`. @notionquest

Comment: can you please try with SQLContext (org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext) once rather than HiveContext? lets check whether that works for you. What is your Spark version?

Comment: Tried that. Still gives the same error. :(  @notionquest

Answer (score 1):

So, Apparently, `com.crealytics.spark.excel` works with spark version 2.0 and above. updating my dependencies and running the jar using spark 2.0 gives the expected result without any errors.

I hope this helps somebody in the future.